# Lazy loading and setting LOCALE_ID at runtime from an API in Angular 8 application on startup

Tags: angular, localization, lazy-loading, angular8

We have an approach for lazy loading and setting the LOCALE_ID of the Angular application from the API (by loading the user profile data during on startup). This worked fine on Angular 7 but when I've upgraded to Angular 8 it stopped working. When the localeFactory is called (see below) the `localeService.getLocale()` is undefined, it has not been initialized yet.
We initialize it in a `SharedResolver` which is in a `SharedModule` which is included in the imports of the `AppModule`.
What is the right approach for doing this in Angular 8? In didn't see anything specific to this in the documentation of changes so I guess it's something indirect.
Any input on what approach I should take here? Thanks

Please see relevant code below:

**app.module.ts**

```
export function localeFactory(localeService: LocaleService) {
    console.log('locale factory called');
    // This is `undefined` here now for some reason
    console.log(localeService.getLocale());

    return localeService.getLocale() || 'en';
}

...
const APP_LOCALE_ID = {
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    deps: [LocaleService],
    useFactory: localeFactory
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule.forRoot(), // <- in this module we have the SharedResolver
        AccountModule,
        ApiModule,
        GenesysSubprojectModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        AppRouteGuard,
        BreadcrumbService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
            deps: [PlatformLocation, BootstrapService],
            multi: true
        },
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
        AppRouteGuard,
        BreadcrumbService,
        // TODO - This doesn't work anymore!
        APP_LOCALE_ID
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**shared-resolve.ts**

```
export class SharedResolve implements Resolve<any> {
    ...

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
       ...

        const observables = forkJoin(
            this.authService.getPermissions(),
            this.authService.getCurrentProfileFromApi(),
            this.languageApi.getActiveLanguages(), // TODO - cache
            this.tenantSettingsApi.getLogo(logoLastModificationTime),
            this.dashboardApi.getDashboardSettings(),
            this.reportApi.getReportSettings(),
            this.publicSettingsApi.getSettings(),
            this.tenantSettingsApi.getInitializationSettings()
        ) as Observable<any[]>;

        return observables
            .pipe(
                flatMap(result => {
                    ...
                    const profile: CurrentUserProfileExtEditDto = result[1];
                    ...
                    const languageName =
                        profile.languageName || navigator.language; // browser default language
                    console.log('Set locale to languageName=' + languageName);
                    this.storageService.setLocale(languageName);
                    this.localeService.setLocale(languageName);
```

Comment: May be an Angular issue, seems to be discussed here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31465

Comment: The issue was fixed in Angular 8.2.1

Comment: But I still experience the problem in angular 9.1.13

Answer (score 10):

Yep, that's an Ivy i18n issue in `v8.x.x`. I've posted it in the Angular repo and has been confirmed by @Ocombe (who is working on Ivy i18n).

If you are in a hurry, as a workaround, you can do this:

As Ivy is searching for a runtime locale, you can simply provide a default language in the `AppModule` like this and then provide your `APP_INITIALIZER`:

```
...
providers: [
    ...
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en' }
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initializeAppSettings,
        deps: [AppInitializerService],
        multi: true
    }
    ...
]
...
```

This will first set the default locale and then run your `APP_INITIALIZER`. Next, in your `CoreModule` (only loaded once), simply provide the new `LOCALE_ID` fetched from the backend:

```
...
providers: [
    ...
    {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        useFactory: (localeService: LocaleService) => localeService.getCurrentLocale(),
        deps: [LocaleService]
    }
    ...
]
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try while we wait for a fix. Strange though, does this affect us even if we do not have Ivy enabled? Or does this mean that we may have Ivy enabled inadvertently?

Comment: It shouldn't... i18n with Ivy is still not complete and simply they forgot about adding an if statemente as you can see in [this commit](https://github.com/ocombe/angular/commit/4628a058c8b3ac67bdac646c3ddee3410c9320d6#diff-b238b48a8829209d017c08882d45b54fR36) referenced at the issue by @Ocombe. As you can see, what are they doing now to fix it is setting a default locale (the same as my workaround) so the app won't break on bootstrap.

Comment: In your example is the locale retrieved inside `initializeAppSettings`? In my case it's a separate `SharedResolver` in a `SharedModule`

Comment: Yes! `initializeAppSettings` is a factory that calls an `AppInitializerService` method, which retrieves the locale for the current logged in user from the backend and stores it in the `LocaleService`. So, when the `getCurrentLocale()` method from `LocaleService` in the `CoreModule` gets executed it already has the locale available to set the `LOCALE_ID` injection token.

Answer (score 0):

What we do in our project is that we actually have lazyloaded modules for each (lang) mutation or "market". This means you use Angular routing and dependency injection to separate i18n related stuff to `<lang>.module.ts` so you have one for each and all the "site" related things are handled in `site.module.ts` which actually holds the application itself

You can see the solution here (yet it does not include the `LOCALE_ID` provide, but you can easily add it there)

https://stackblitz.com/github/vmasek/angular-typed-translations-demo

---

I wrote a blog post about this alternative i18n approach and typing the translations. You can read more about it here https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-typed-translations-29353f0a60bc